# Why is drive/partition number still used?

Tags: partition, grub2, disk, boot-loader, uuid

Many times, especially when messing around with boot-loaders, I'll see numerical drive and partition numbers used. For instance, in my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` I see `set root='hd0,gpt2'`, my UEFI boot entries often reference drive/partition numbers, and it seems to crop up in almost any context where bootloaders are concerned.

Now that we have UUID and PARTUUID, addressing partitions in this manner seems incredibly unstable (afaik, drives are not guaranteed to be mounted in the same order always, a user may move the order of drives being plugged into their mobo, etc.)

My questions therefore are twofold:

1. Is this addressing scheme as unstable as I have outlined above? Am I missing something in the standard that means this scheme is far more reliable than I expect, or will this addressing scheme truly render your system unbootable (until you fix your boot entries at least) as a result of your drives simply being recognized in a different order or plugging them into different slots on your motherboard?
2. If the answer to the question above is yes, then why does this addressing scheme continue to be used? Wouldn't using UUID or PARTUUID for everything be far more stable, and consistent?

Comment: The BIOS used the drive numbers, UEFI *can* use the numbers (not sure if it can use UUID, too) and grub etc. just map the UUIDs to the numbers used. So even if you put UUIDs in every configuration file, chances are high that on the lower level it's still drive numbers. Drivers numbers are BIOS/UEFI/hardware dependent and "unstable", partition numbers are well-defined and "stable".

Comment: I notice you are talking about UEFI. Note that UEFI only exists on about 10% of the platforms that Linux supports, even less if you include other Unices and Unixoids. In fact, even on the CPU architectures that UEFI is used on (IA-32, AMD64, and IA-64), there are non-UEFI systems. PCs before UEFI used something called "BIOS", and BIOS-based PCs are still around. Plus, there are non-PC x86/AMD64 based platforms that use e.g. OpenFirmware, coreboot, or sometimes even no platform firmware at all! Not all filesystems have UUIDs. Not all partitioning schemes have UUIDs. And so on …

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag that makes sense! I've found it's pretty widely accepted that BIOS booting will "probably" work most of the time and people don't question it beyond that because it's so widely used. I was curious as to whether or not UEFI had fixed some of the above-mentioned problems with BIOS lacking implementation guarantees, but it looks like we still rely on it working "well enough". Oh well... I'll just get it working and not touch it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The plain numbering scheme is not actually used in recent systems (with "recent" being Ubuntu 9 and later, other distributions may have adapted in that era, too).
You are correct in observing the root partition is set with the plain numbering scheme. But this only is a default or fall-back setting which is usually overridden with the very next command, such as:

```
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 74686973-6973-616e-6578-616d706c650a
```

This selects the root partition based on the file-system's UUID.

In practice, the plain numbering scheme is usually stable (as long as there are no hardware changes). The only instance I observed non-predictable numbering was system with many USB-drives which were enumerated based on a first-come-first serve pattern and then emulated as IDE drives. None of these processes are inherently chaotic, so I assume a problem in that particular systems BIOS implementation.

Note: "root partition" in this context means the partition to boot from, it may be different from the partition containing the "root aka. / file system".

Comment: I went back and looked, and you're right that I must have missed that very next line in my config file -- that makes a lot more sense. My UEFI boot entries also use this raw numbering (for instance, SATA(0x3, 0x0, 0x0). Does this mean that my UEFI boot entries will also cease to work if I move my drives around?

Comment: @quixotrykd I have no idea. I would not be surprised if it is not defined by any standard and consequently depends on the particular EFI implementation of your system.

Comment: It is also unstable with NVMe devices, the device number depends on detection order not slot order, at least I had some machines where PCIe card based NVMes switched their number (after reboot and probably kernel update)

Answer (score 20):

Strictly speaking, *UUID is not addressing* at all.

Addressing is very, very simple: read drive X sector Y - or else. Read memory address Z - or else. Addressing is simple, fast, leaves not much room for interpretation, and it's everywhere.

UUID is not addressing. Instead it's searching, finding, sometimes waiting for devices to appear, and also *understanding filesystems*(★). And depending how many devices there are, it may take a very long time. And once found, back to regular addressing it is.

In GRUB, this is called `search`(★★) and it's only available when GRUB has already grown wings (search is a module, as is every filesystem it supports, thus only available after loading core). In Linux, it's (for example) called `findfs`, *findfs will search the block devices in the system looking for a filesystem or partition*.

It goes through all blockdevices, wakes them from standby, reads data, and the result may even still be random if the UUID is not unique as it should be (after `dd` accident or the like), or you get no result if the UUID changed - UUIDs are prone to configuration errors, too.

In general, UUIDs are great, and of course you should use them everywhere if available, especially when traditional addressing is bound to fail because drive order is random in Linux; but understand that the complexity is above and beyond what simple addressing is meant to do. And especially in the very early stages of bootloaders, it simply might not be an option yet. Addressing comes first, growing wings comes later.

For the bootloader, it might simply not be necessary to make the effort (not every bootloader supports a wide range of filesystems like GRUB). If `hd0` is guaranteed to be "the disk we booted off of" due to circumstance (the BIOS provides), and so if you can rule out random drive order issues, there may be no need to go through a potentially enormous list of other partitions in search for UUIDs.

If you're confident enough in your configuration to say that `hd0,gpt2` is the one you want, and it has to be, and it can't be otherwise, then there is nothing wrong with using it like that. Sometimes, plain and simple addressing works just fine.

---

(★) I previously explained this [for LABELs here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528829/30851)...

> There is no generic standard for labels, it's all hand-knitted, see for example [this implementation of superblocks formats in util-linux](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/tree/master/libblkid/src/superblocks). If you invent a new filesystem tomorrow, even if it has a label, it won't show up until support is added.

...and it's much the same for UUIDs.

---

(★★) Actually, GRUB's `search` has a `--hint` option, and... now I haven't checked the source code, and it's not even documented in their manual, but such an option would make sense to give you the best of both worlds: the hint should tell `search` to *check that partition first*, and if the UUID matches as expected, it identified the device with *minimal effort*, and if it doesn't match, it'll still fall back to the full blown search to keep things working somehow.

In addition to that, previously found UUIDs tend to be cached, so it doesn't have to go through all devices all over again and again and again - and this too works great, provided the UUID you're looking for actually exists somewhere to make it into the cache in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

Also do not forget labels. They aren't as unique as UUIDs, but much more informative, and make your fstab human readable. If it's your desktop, or a small company--in other words, you are managing a few to a few dozens drives, you may prefer labels to UUIDs.

Musing over @frostschutz's [excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532448/103076) to your question, one scenario when you would likely prefer the "classic" device link addressing is the VM setup, especially in the VM-for-hire (abbreviated, confusingly, “IaaS”) clouds. Suppose you want to customize an *Ubunzima 04.18* image. You create a (throwaway) VM with 2 disks: one will be the (throwaway) system drive, and the second the one you mount and customize. Presumably, you also mount its UEFI boot partition, if you want to grub a newer grub on your new disk. Assuming you've chosen mount points for the target partitions under `/mnt`, your desired mount table looks like

```
/dev/sda1    /
/dev/sda9    /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1    /mnt/root
/dev/sdb9    /mnt/efi
```

So you make 2 identical drives from the existing, provider-provided, cloud-ready image, connect them to a new VM and boot it. Naturally,

- All modern OS distros, our imaginary *Ubunzima 04.18* not being an exception, rely on UUID-named mounts.
- All hard drives rolled out from the same image have the same UUID. UUIDs are unique, so what could go wrong?

You already see whither this is all going.

The first time this frankencontraption booted, it picked `sda9` as the EFI boot partition, but Linux decided to remount `sdb1` as the root FS:

```
/dev/sda1    /mnt/root
/dev/sdb1    /
/dev/sda9    /boot/efi
/dev/sdb9    /mnt/efi
```

And since my roll-out script was quite unprepared for that, I've got an unbootable dud image in the end, without a single tool complaining in the log during the frankenbuild!

*Of course* I printed the mount table in the logs. And *of course* the mess-up is very hard to spot, since mount(8) prints mounts in the order halfway between random and that in which the devices were mounted, so it was not surprising I did not spot it right away. And imagine, the same script (but with disks from different images) previously worked as smooth as 15-year-old Glenfiddich. Guess how many hours I spent pulling my hair¹ over the log trying to figure out the problem?

---

There are no hard and fast rules good for any situation, from a desktop PC to a Linux embedded in a router to your Android phone to a cloud data center. A SO answer is supposed to be objective, and my experiences or preferences are, of course, not. So I would rather show examples of logical reasoning when selecting among different methods of identifying partitions:

- **Leave it alone** if you have no reason not to. The UUIDs is the default for most modern distros. If it comes to adding a second drive, try then and decide. Chances are you won't ever need to even know. If your system still boots and you can see and partition the new device, format and add it to fstab (by UUID, by LABEL or by a `/dev` link, same considerations apply). It's only when your system refuses to boot after plugging in the extra drive, then you have a problem (and maybe changing the boot order in the UEFI BIOS is the quickest way out).

  Pragmatically, labeling which SATA connector goes to which drive in your own desktop may be the fastest and easiest solution, while changing the way the system boots and recovering from a quite likely boot failure is, arguably, the worst time-gobbler. But if you manage it for 50 programmers who think that throwing in an extra drive is not a problem worthy bothering you, at the very least do not test the limits of your luck and make sure their initial boot drives are all seen by grub as `hd0` and the system as `sda`.
- **Labels** to manage your own drives and partitions in your desktop or three, or a small milieu (a sitting room of a house packed with software engineers who funnily call the place their “startup office”). If you pull a physical drive from someone's machine, you know where it came from if you use labels consistently.

  If lsblk(8) says `LABEL=bubba-boot`, you know it has been pulled from the machine called *bubba*; besides, *bubba-boot* rolls over my tongue much easier than *6864c4ea-f9b9-46db-b875-4d7fc2981007*, which, to my spoiled taste, is downright a jawbreaker. Ensuring that labels are unique now shifts upon you, but what you get in return is the label's meaningfulness.
- **`/dev`-link based** naming when commanding a battalion of relatively short-living, low-maintenance VMs which are the spawn of the same image, and you would not bet your weekly wage that all their UUID live up to the UU promise. Any *sane* VM service, be it *Vyper-H* on your own physical server or *Kugel Cloud* or anything, shall never call your boot drive `sde`, and the second and the only other one `sdc`². In a physical machine, on the other hand, you can easily get that same arrangement by creatively connecting SATA cables.

  I digress now, but in this scenario, I go same route with the so-called “consistent” Ethernet interface naming: disable it in VMs. Don't get me wrong, the naming is really consistent as long as the NIC you put into the PCI slot 4 won't suddenly jump to slot 5 on its own whim while you are not looking (or maybe even while you are; NICs have no shame whatsoever). Unfortunately, in the “battalion of VMs” milieu they in fact do. In this case, counter-intuitively, `eth0` is *more* consistent than `enp0s4f6`. The VM provider did not promise to always put their virtual NIC number 1 in the slot 4 on the PCI bus 0 (and none of the 3 mentioned entities are physically real), and that it will always be the Function 6. But you can pretty much rely on the first interface going before the second, considering they normally have the same driver module, commonly from the virtio family (and if the first NIC is not always `eth0`, the same note² still applies).

  ---

¹ Figuratively, of course. I've been if this business for far too long to have any left.
² If they did, I'd seriously consider <s>running away screaming from them</s> changing the provider or the VM hypervisor software.

Answer (score 3):

Both schemes can be mixed and matched with most linux distributions.

The consequences can be desirable or undesirable depending on use case - for example, one might prefer the older scheme (and even disable udev-style persistence hacks) if hot replacement of (virtual hardware or actual hardware) drives without having to modify configuration files is wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your second question ("why does this addressing scheme continue to be used?") is, I guess, inertia. Yes, it is totally possible to use only UUIDs on GPT partitioned disks. You can use UUIDs instead of `/dev/xxx` names in `/etc/fstab`. And now that we have the [Discoverable Partitions Specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/DiscoverablePartitionsSpec/), in many cases you don't even have to specify the UUIDs anymore, just partition your disk with the partition type and the partitions will be picked up automatically. On my machine the `root=` entry is missing altogether from the kernel command line.

And speaking of boot loaders: GRUB is mostly superfluous on modern UEFI PCs, in the sense that it has very little to do with bootstrapping the machine. Nowadays GRUB merely functions as a kernel chooser program, for which task there are simpler and better alternatives available, like systemd-boot.